# How to remove characters with a specific ASCII value using a text editor?

Tags: binary, notepad++, ascii, non-printing-characters

How can I remove all characters that have a specific decimal ASCII value?

Can Notepad++ do that? Otherwise, is there another software I can use?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Notepad++  you can use `\x41` to find `A`.  Use `\x` to match escaped hexadecimal codes.

For this, you need to tick `Regular Expression` and `Match Case` options in the Replace window.

Comment: So, to remove SUB which has Dec 26, I should write in the replace window \x26 to be substituted with nothing. And I do have to check the 2nd of the square ticks and the 3rd of the round ticks. .... However I have tried but the notepad finds for me &, which has Hx 26 and not Dec...

Comment: @Elena: You have to convert dec to hex before, so SUB (dec 26) is hex 1A. use `\x1A` in "Find what".